# XCode8 initWithCoder frame Size

Tags: xcode8, initwithcoder

Found if use XCode 8 XIB file, the UIView initWithCoder will get frame (0, 0, 1000, 1000) instead of the XIB frame size setting.

Check the diff of XIB xml file it will add

```
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
```

and remove rect frame settings such as

```
<rect key="frame" x="110" y="0.0" width="20" height="17"/>
```

Removing rect frame setting is the major root cause to get width 1000 and height 1000 in the initWithCoder.

Therefore, any related size calculation, we need to handle in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: I think this is solved in Xcode 8.1