# Opening/editing a xib/storyboard in Xcode 8 GM results in layout crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, xcode8

If I so much as open a xib or storyboard in `Xcode` 8 GM and choose a device/orientation to "View as" parts of my code involving custom `UIView` classes start crashing hard when I build and run my app. This applies to any edit I make to a xib/storyboard as well.

Here's my call stack for my custom `UIView` that's crashing after setting my "View as" in my main storyboard (also happens every time in xibs):

`initWithCoder`
`layoutIfNeeded` (called after I call `setNeedsLayout`)

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry',
>   reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [97 nan]'
>
> First throw call stack: (0x182adedb0 0x182143f80 0x182adecf8
>   0x1855b95d4 0x1855b9530 0x1012d2474 0x1855b94c8 0x18822d05c
>   0x18822ced8 0x18822d008 0x187c30618 0x187c421cc 0x1885a5ed8
>   0x187c83a48 0x187c341e4 0x1855c298c 0x1855bd5c8 0x187c4b0a4
>   0x1001c2b0c 0x1001c19ac 0x10010cecc 0x1881106b0 0x188234438
>   0x1882345b0 0x188234180 0x187f420e4 0x188234438 0x188234180
>   0x1835957b0 0x188234438 0x1882345b0 0x188234180 0x1884d44c0
>   0x188234438 0x188234180 0x1835957b0 0x1881106b0 0x188234438
>   0x188234180 0x188110354 0x188234438 0x1882345b0 0x188234180
>   0x18810f688 0x187fb1230 0x187d76118 0x187c388ec 0x187c38844
>   0x187c3f59c 0x187c3ca88 0x187cb2fa4 0x187ede3ac 0x187ee25f0
>   0x187edf764 0x18447f7ac 0x18447f618 0x18447f9c8 0x182a9509c
>   0x182a94b30 0x182a92830 0x1829bcc50 0x187ca794c 0x187ca2088
>   0x10027d938 0x18255a8b8)

Any insight into this issue is much appreciated. I assume things haven't been "laid out" yet, and maybe triggering a layout in `initWithCoder` is poor form, but it's never been an issue before and it's only an issue with xibs/storyboards in `Xcode` 8 GM.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone stumbling upon this in the future from Google I'm pretty sure the issue can be explained by these two posts:

[XCode8 initWithCoder frame Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631583/xcode8-initwithcoder-frame-size)

[Proper practice for subclassing UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978370/proper-practice-for-subclassing-uiview)

In short: Xcode 8 changes xibs such that they don't report a (bogus) frame to `UIView's` `initWithCoder`, causing my crashes. As inquired/suspected it is poor form to do any layout in `initWithCoder`. Xcode 8 is simply forcibly correcting my error.